# Jquery Toggle div on clicking Panel header using + and - symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a panel. when I click on **+** symbol Panel body should be displayed. and **+** should get converted to **-** and when I click on **-** then panel body should collapse.

But there is a slight change in that.

[image: By default panel div should be like this]

[image: Open panel on clicking + symbol like this]

So when 1st time page reloads then the panel should be like 1st image and when click on **+** symbol it opens panel div.

Note : There is by default text written in **panel body** a single line , it will be removed when clicking on **+** symbol and open the panel body contents.

```js
$('.open_discount_div').toggle(function(){
        $(".open_discount_div").text("-");
        $(".show_hide_panel").slideDown();

    },function(){
        $(".open_discount_div").text("-");
        $(".show_hide_panel").slideUp();
    });
```

```css
.show_hide_panel{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="panel panel-default set_margin_0 set_padding_0" >
                <div class="panel-heading text-left ticket_panel_body_bg">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-10 ">
                            <span>Add Discount </span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2 ">
                            <span class="pull-right cursor_pointer open_discount_div">+</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



              <div class="panel-body set_padding_0">
                    DIscount Type , Code
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body set_padding_0 show_hide_panel">
                        Data To be displayed on clicking + symbol
                </div>
```

Some how i don't see **+** symbol in the beginning.

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uowLfpyt/)

Any help would be great.

Thank You

Comment: create a JSfiddle so we can have a look

Comment: Yes.. added in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is with your event handler. You have not attached the event handler anywhere in the code.

```
$('.open_discount_div').on('click', function () {
    if($(this).text() === "+" ) {
    $(this).text("-");
    $('.show_hide_panel').slideDown();
  } else {
    $(this).text("+");
    $('.show_hide_panel').slideUp();
  }

});
```

Try the above code or check the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uowLfpyt/4/)

Comment: Oh yeah.. great... just one request... i want to add font awesome **plus** and **minus** class instead of text. so is this possible?

Comment: Try font-awesome. Look at their website and the documentation

Comment: i have used but at the time of jquery. i dont know how to include class.

Comment: There's **$(el).addClass(classname)** function to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You have both '-' defined,

Try this,

```
$('.open_discount_div').toggle(function(){
        $(".open_discount_div").text("-");
        $(".show_hide_panel").slideDown();

    },function(){
        $(".open_discount_div").text("+");
        $(".show_hide_panel").slideUp();
    });
```

Comment: i can't see + , when page reloads

Comment: you can check in JSFiddle